# How to run 2 tasks with different commands

Tags: visual-studio-code

From VS Code, I'd like to run two different tasks using different `command`s: one would be `xbuild` (or `msbuild`) to build the server-side app from C# sources and the other would be `tsc` to build client-side Javascript from TypeScript. The only problem is that, apparently, one can specify a single `command` is `tasks.json`.

Yes, I know I can use gulp or grunt and call that task runner from VS Code but I'd like to not add yet another dependency to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bash/batch script for the `command` value. The task's `taskName` will be passed as the first argument to that script when executed as long as you don't set `suppressTaskName` true.

Inside the script you check the value of the first argument in order to execute the correct command.

A sample Windows batch script looks like this

```
if /i %1%==test (
  msbuild MyTestProject.csproj
) else (
  msbuild MyProjectFile.csproj
)
```

Comment: Nice trick but I'd better like to avoid writing build script - I am trying to get rid of a `build.sh` file after all. ;)

Comment: As far as I know there is no other solution.